# Event.target.name works for input but not div?

Tags: html, reactjs

The `onBlur` `handleBlur` function outputs the value from the `name` attribute for the `input` tag, but `undefined` for the `div` tag. Why does it not output the value from the `name` attribute for the `div` tag as well?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Editable extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  handleBlur(event) {
    console.log(event.target, event.target.name);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div
          name={this.props.name}
          contentEditable={true}
          onBlur={this.handleBlur}
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.props.html }}
        />
        <input name={this.props.name} onBlur={this.handleBlur} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<div>`s don't have a `name` **property**. You can have an attribute, but a property is something else (more down below).

Also, because the value of `this.props.name` is empty, React is not rendering the attribute, which makes you get `null` even if you try to get the attribute. So try do add some value to the attribute and log `event.target.getAttribute('name')` as below:

```
 handleBlur(event) {
    console.log(event.target, event.target.name);
    console.log(event.target, event.target.getAttribute('name'));       // added this
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div
          name={this.props.name + "SOMETHING"}                         // added this
          contentEditable={true}
          onBlur={this.handleBlur}
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.props.html }}
        />
        <input name={this.props.name} onBlur={this.handleBlur} />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

The above would output:

```
<div name=​"undefinedSOMETHING" contenteditable=​"true">​</div>​ undefined
<div name=​"undefinedSOMETHING" contenteditable=​"true">​</div>​ "undefinedSOMETHING"
```

---

More about the `div` and `name` property:

```js
console.log(document.getElementById("d").name)
console.log(document.getElementById("i").name)
console.log('---');
console.log(document.getElementById("d").getAttribute('name'))
console.log(document.getElementById("i").getAttribute('name'))
```

```html
<div id="d" name="alice"></div>
<input id="i" name="bob">
```

Docs:

- [`HTMLInputElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement): there's a `name` property.
- [`HTMLDivElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDivElement): all properties are inherited and its parent (`HTMLElement`) has no `name` either.